# when defining a call centre in open cti how to configure the call center number?

Tags: cti

I am facing problem when defining a call center in salesforce open cti how to configure the call center number ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you're asking...

Generally softphone settings are stored in an associated SF Call Center Definition (CCD).  A CCD is an XML file provided by you for an SF admin to import into the org.  Once imported it creates one or more setting that your softphone can query for using the open CTI method getCallCenterSettings.